# Call program from another subfolder

Tags: python, call

I wrote an application in Python, the programs reside in the main folder named "A1". In this folder, I created a subfolder called "A2".

From a program that resides in the "A1" folder, I have to call a Python program that resides in the "A2" folder. I can not recall it.

Comment: By "call a program" you mean "import a module"? Or do you actually want to _execute_ a python script as a standalone program?

Comment: @Aran-Fey you're all over the place or what ? :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Working hard to earn my python hammer :(

Comment: 181 to go... can take a little while :) you seem ready to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `__init.py__` file in `A2`, which will make the directory a python package.

Then in the file in `A1` you can do:

```
import A2.file_to_run
file_to_run.method_to_run()
```

If you want to execute the whole file, you can do(warning this is a very wrong way of doing it):

```
import os
execfile(os.path.join('A2','file_to_run.py'))
```

This is a very wrong and a very hacky way of doing this, you should go with the first method of importing the file then calling the method.